# Cordova Windows Project Setup

Tags: windows, cordova, command-line-interface

I have created a new cordova windows application (not WP8) using CLI.
I followed the following procedure,

```
cordova create xyz com.compname.wxyz XYZ<br>
cd xyz<br>
cordova platform add windows<br>
cordova plugin add blah! blah! blah!<br>
cordova build windows<br>
cordova run windows<br>
```

When i run the above codes in command promp everything runs fine until "cordova build windows", but when i run "cordova run windows" it shows a lot of errors,

```
Error: Could not install the package.<br>
Starting application...<br>
Get-AppxPackage : The package repository is corrupted.<br>
The package repository is corrupted.<br>
```

when i try to run the project it says error log as,

```
Error   1   Error : DEP0600 : The following unexpected error occurred during deployment: <br>
The package repository is corrupted.<br>
The package repository is corrupted.    CordovaApp.Windows80<br>
```

Does anyone have any idea what is going on or can someone tell me how to successfully create a new cordova windows project using CLI or manually.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have Microsoft Visual Studio installed and you're running on a Windows 8 system?

What happens when you open the solution in Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes. When i open VS nothing happens, but when i try to run app on simulator it shows the above mentioned error. I tried re installing  VS and Mobile SDK8.0 still no luck. At last i "Refresh" my os. and installed VS and mob sdk, now everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is because your deployment environment you targeting is not being recognized by the deploying platform you are using.

*in short your device in which you want to deploy the appxBundle is not being identified by your computer.*

I hope this helps...

**Tell me you want to deploy it on windows which OS version.
1) windows 10 [ARM/x86]
2) windows 8.1 [ARM/x86]**

Let me know if it helps.